# .class extension for php

Tags: php, class, file-extension

I have been digging in the drupal installation folder and found some .inc file. So they stand for 'include', but I'm wondering if there are .class extension for PHP made to distinguish that the file is a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.class` extension is typically used for [Java classfiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file). While there's no technical reason why you can't use it for your PHP include files, doing so will be confusing to other developers, as it may associate the files with a Java virtual machine, rather than with a text editor. It may additionally open you to some security issues: `.class` files, as well as `.inc` files, will be made available for download if they are directly accessible from your web root. Both from a security perspective and for the benefit of other developers, you're best off using the `.php` extension for all PHP files.

Comment: On a side note: you can make `.class` files be processed by PHP by adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php .class` to the `.htaccess`.